# "Failed to meet resource limits for operation' getting this error while creating blueprint in aws lake formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I am trying to create new blueprint  in aws lake formation, but it's giving me error saying "Failed to meet resource limits for operation". How to resolve this issue

tried deleting few old blueprint, but still not working